# How to hide attribute to be seen in DOM in angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, dom, browser, angularjs-directive

I am trying to hide some sensitive data to not display in DOM.

I am using [Angular directive](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/guide/directive)

I have tried to search a little bit and found that we can hide/show HTML element using ng-hide/ng-show.

> But i want to permanently hide the attribute (In my case, Its a google
>   map api key) to be hidden in DOM.

How can i do that?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is your API key in a DOM attribute, to start with?

Comment: Good question!
I think your question gave me answer :D
Right now we are implementing mechanism so that our clients can make widget by their own and in this google map case, We need to get this value to build the map widget.
But I think we need to modify the architecture. 
Thanks @Kaddath!

Comment: you're welcome, always glad to help!